# How to launch App Info for a android package

Tags: android

```
Intent intent_as = new Intent(
                    android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_SETTINGS);

            startActivity(intent_as);
```

Using the above code I can get a screen with list of apps installed. How to Get to the app info page of a selected application.

Basically it should be something like add some extra data to intent (package name) but I am not able to find a way to do it?

Are things anywhere documented properly in android

Comment: You should use `android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS`instead of `android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_SETTINGS` , and set the package name of your app as Data to the intent. See my answer below

Comment: I am making code compatible to 2.2 so ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS wont work there

Answer (score 18):

You should use `android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS` instead of `android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_SETTINGS` , and set the **package name** of your app as Data to the intent.

try this  :

```
//redirect user to app Settings
Intent i = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
i.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + getPackageName()));
startActivity(i);
```

Comment: Getting following eror: Thread [<1> main] (Suspended (exception ActivityNotFoundException)) 
 <VM does not provide monitor information> 
 Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(int, Object) line: 1536 
 Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Context, IBinder, IBinder, Activity, Intent, int) line: 1388 
 MainActivity(Activity).startActivityForResult(Intent, int) line: 3195 
 MainActivity(Activity).startActivity(Intent) line: 3302 
 MainActivity.onClick(View) line: 302 
 Button(View).performClick() line: 3571 
 View$PerformClick.run() line: 14247

Comment: Does this work? Can you open other app info as well? - of course, if you know the package name

Comment: i've just tried it and it works, which api level are you targetting ? and what is the package name you are passing the the intent ? try to use the method getPackageName() or verify your package name if you pass it as a String ( like "com.company.myapp")

Comment: the `android.provider.Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS` is added in api level 9 ( Android 2.3 FROYO), so if your minSdkVersion is < 9 , so this code will not work on devices with Android version <= 2.2 ( api level 8)

Comment: @gunar : yes you can , and of course you should know the packageName of the app that you want to open its settings

Answer (score 0):

I test it for **SDK R (30) - Android 11**
This way you can use Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS and set the package name of your app as Data to the intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
   intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
   Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", this.getPackageName(), null);
   intent.setData(uri);
   startActivity(intent);
```

If you want access to the app **Permission**:

```
 intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_APP_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Kotlin version

you have to create a context variable in Compose like

```
val context = LocalContext.current
```

and then use it in the code

```
val intent = Intent()
intent. Action = Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS
val uri = Uri.fromParts("package", context.packageName, null)
intent. Data = uri
context.startActivity(intent)
```